# PHP get table structure

Tags: php

I have the following function that returns all of the required table information for the columns ect.  It works great until I amend the table structure. If I add a new column and run the code,  it still returns the information  the original  table structure information.

So, how do I get it to return the information including any changes to the columns etc.?
Thanks in advance.

```
$columns = array();

try {
    $rs = $dbo->query('SELECT * FROM '.$thisTable.' LIMIT 0');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rs->columnCount(); $i++) {
        $columns[$i] = $rs->getColumnMeta($i);
    }
    $arr = array('ERROR' => 'SUCCESS');
    $thisData = array_merge($arr, $columns);
} catch(PDOException $pe) {
    $thisData = array('ERROR' => 'NODATA');
}
return $thisData;
```

Comment: Can you explain what `$dbo` is? Does it have any documentation?

Comment: Why not use [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html);

Comment: hi,$dbo is the connection

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

In your way, when the table is empty you will get empty array.